# How many watts does an electrical appliance consume?

Tags: power

This question is based on the following image:

[image]

https://superuser.com/questions/587869/how-can-i-determine-how-many-amps-i-need-to-power-my-laptop

> Electrical power equation: Power P = I × V

> where power P is in watts,
>
> current I is in amperes (DC) and
>
> voltage V is in volts.

However, there are 2 different currents (A) and voltages given for this laptop.

Q1. Which one should be used to calculate power?

1. `INPUT` number

Information given: `100-240V ~ 1.5A(1,5A)    50-60Hz`

Pmin = 1.5A x 100V
= 150.0 Watt

Pmax = 1.5A x 240V
= 360.0 Watt

or

2. `OUTPUT` number

Information given: `19V : 3.42A(3,42A)`

P = 3.42A x 19V = 64.98 Watt

Q2. Why are there 2 different voltages `100-240V` in the `INPUT` section?

Q3. What are the difference between `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` in this image?

Comment: *"Why are there 2 different voltages 100/240V in the input section?"* It says "100-240 V" (i.e. it works at any voltage within this range), it's NOT "100/240 V" (i.e. it works only at 100 V or 240 V). A wide input range is typical in a modern switched-mode power supply.

Comment: Thanks @比尔盖子, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

> Q1. Which one should be used to calculate power?
> Input or output power

Well, that depends on what you care about. But my guess is how much total power you consume, not how much comes out of your supply, so it's the input.

However, that current is a  *peak* current of what the supply will draw in a transient situation (plugging it in), so it has nothing to do with power consumption and the approach of simply multiplying the current with the voltage will not take you anywhere.

That's like plugging in a lamp to your outlet, then walking over to your breaker cabinet, see that it's all 10A breakers, and claim that therefore, any lamp you plug into your 220V outlet will consume 2.2 kW. That's not how it works.

Same for the output rating: that's probably maximum continuous power, and there's very few appliances that really have a constant power consumption.

So, the data given on your supply addresses something else than what you care about.

In this situation, the only way forward is actually measuring power consumption in real-world usage. In-line pluggable power meters are < 15€ ...

> Q2. Why are there 2 different voltage 100/240V in input section.

Because the same supply can be used with multiple grid voltages.

> Q3. What are the difference between input and output in this image?

See Q1.

Comment: Also worth mentioning power factor here, I think. The input's AC, and these power supplies tend to have a pretty poor power factor.

Comment: @Hearth that looks like a relatively modern laptop power brick supply, and I'd expect them to be well-PFC'ed.

Comment: It's still probably not unity power factor, though.

Comment: I suspect it has passive PFC (brings the power factor up to 0.7 or so from the 0.5 or so of an uncorrected supply) but not active (brings the power factor up to damn near unity).

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it

The current on the label is the maximum current the supply can be expected to draw in worst-case normal operation (not the switch-on surge, that may well be significantly higher).

The voltage on the label is the range of *nominal* voltages the supply is expected to operate from. The supply is designed for use all over the world and the 100V to 240V range of nominal voltages covers all the bases, the 100V nominal voltage is used in Japan. The 240V nominal voltage was the old nominal voltage in the UK and I think a few ex-colonies of the UK may still use it.

There are a few factors that mean the current on the label is often higher than one would expect.

- your equation assumes unity power factor. A supply that small is unlikely to have active power factor correction. So the power factor may only be 0.7 or so.
- the actual input voltage range The supply is designed for will be wider than the nominal input voltage range to allow for supply tolerances and volt drop, something like 80V or 90V at the low end to to 264V at the high end. The current on the rating label is likely to be based on operation at the low end of the input voltage range.
- Power supplies are not perfectly efficient, while some of the best power supplies can get over 90%, a more typical value would be 80% or so.
- Safety regulators aren't bothered the manufacturer overstates the current needs but doesn't like it if they understate them.

The output power of your PSU is about 65W. So what is the maximum input current based on these assumptions? well we need to take the output power and divide it by the efficiency, the power factor and the minimum input voltage.

65W / 0.8 / 0.7 / 80 = 1.45

Round that off to the next tenth of an amp and you get the value printed on the label.

Of course the actual current in normal service is likely to be lower, the laptop is unlikely to draw max power out of the PSU all the time and the voltage of your supply is unlikely to be at the very bottom end of the power supply's input range.